# EGit timeout with TALEND

Tags: timeout, talend, egit

I have trouble with Egit plugin under talend. When pushing, it fails with message *timeout exceeded 30 000ms*. Under eclipse, there is a menu **team** where I can change the timeout value, but talend doesn't have this. How can this value be changed under talend. Thank's for your help.